# How to handle pipes producing empty data further down the dplyr pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

This issue occurs in `dplyr` version 0.30.

I have a chain of pipes `%>%` starting with a `filter`. Sometimes this filter reduces the data frame to no rows. Some where further down the pipe line, I have a function which uses `if` to mutate the data frame. However, this function errors if the data frame has been reduced to zero rows prior.

For example

```
data(mtcars)

stupid_function <- function(x){
    if( x == 6){
        return(2*x)
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
}

for(i in 6:10) {

    data <-
        mtcars %>% 
        filter(cyl == i) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(carb2 = stupid_function(carb)) %>%
        group_by(carb2) %>%
        summarise(mean(wt))

    print(data)

}
```

works for `i = 6` but fails for `i = 7`, e.g.

Is there anyway to handle this problem? Two approaches I have considered is breaking up the chain in the middle to check that the data has more than one row after filtering, or wrapping everything in a `tryCatch`.

Comment: note that in this case the corresponding `ifelse` code representing `stupid_function` works fine: `for(i in 6:10) {
    
    data <-
        mtcars %>% 
        filter(cyl == i) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(carb2 = ifelse(carb == 6, 2*carb, carb)) %>%
        group_by(carb2) %>%
        summarise(mean(wt))
    
    print(data)
    
}` and produces `NaN`s where the data does not exist.

Comment: There are no seven cylinder cars that I know of.  Pretty much always even.  Perhaps you should write the code based on what you know about the data.  You'd have another problem at nine cylinders

Comment: Fair point. But in this case I do not know a priori what will exist or not. As an example, suppose we wish to give summary statistics for each of 4, 6, 8 cylinder cars existing at a car dealership. The car dealship supplies data in a format like the `mtcars` set. Then it is quite plausible they do not sell 8 cylinder cars and the code will crash.

Comment: Well you don't have to use all `dplyr` functions in a chain.  You could maybe stick an `ifelse` in there to get past the issue.  But I'm not really understanding the purpose of the `for` loop.  Are you just trying to return a one-row "summary" each iteration? There really shouldn't be a need for any `for` loops with `dplyr`

Comment: It's just an example. Let's say I wanted to write a pdf report with 3 sections on each of the possible cylinder types.

Comment: @Richard - 5-cylinder cars [exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight-five_engine), and then there's [this 7-cylinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDsmTeQXVME) ;)

Comment: @jbaums Hahaha, of course.  I knew that comment would come back to bite me in the butt.

Comment: @Richard To be fair, that's an aircraft engine mounted on the VW. Probably fairly unlikely that such a model would show up in `mtcars`.

Comment: Can't you trap for NULL or x of size 0 in `stupid_function` itself so it doesn't fire on empty inputs?

Comment: @Avraham That sounds good. What do you suppose `stupid_function` should return if a length zero argument is passed to it? I suppose I could examine the code in `?ifelse` to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the latest version of `dplyr` (0.4.0), filter no longer crashes, but [returns its input when the output is 0-sized](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md)(see #782), so you may no longer have your error. Specifically:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

stupid_function <- function(x){
  if(x == 6){
    return(2 * x)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

for(i in 6:10) {

  data <-
    mtcars %>% 
    filter(cyl == i) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(carb2 = stupid_function(carb)) %>%
    group_by(carb2) %>%
    summarise(mean(wt))

  print(data)

}
```

Returns:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  carb2 mean(wt)
1     1  3.33750
2     4  3.09375
3    12  2.77000
Source: local data frame [0 x 2]

Variables not shown: carb2 (dbl), mean(wt) (dbl)
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  carb2 mean(wt)
1     2 3.560000
2     3 3.860000
3     4 4.433167
4     8 3.570000
Source: local data frame [0 x 2]

Variables not shown: carb2 (dbl), mean(wt) (dbl)
Source: local data frame [0 x 2]

Variables not shown: carb2 (dbl), mean(wt) (dbl)
Warning messages:
1: Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature 
2: Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature 
3: Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature 
4: Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature 
5: Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

You may also want to trap for 0-sized input in `stupid_function` with something like this:

```
stupid_function <- function(x = NULL) {
  if (is.null(x)) {
    return(0)
  } else if(x == 6) {
    return(2 * x)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}
```

This pre-allocates NULL to x and assigns 0 (or you could assign NULL) as the return if nothing else populates it.

Comment: oh, I will update my dplyr version and see what happens. This is awesome, thanks!

Comment: confirmed, updating to 0.40 fixed this issue.